# VueJS adding transition on new data view

Tags: vue.js

I want to add some transition effect on newly created element on VueJS. Like in the following code if I create a new list element using the input field, I want it to appear using 'fade' or 'slide-in' effect. I couldn't figure out it from the official documentation. how can I do that?

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#vue-instance",
    data: {
        newelement: '',
        list: []
    },
    methods: {
        addelement: function() {
            this.list.push(this.newelement);
            this.newelement = '';
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="vue-instance">
    <input type="text" v-model="newelement" @keyup.enter="addelement">
    <ul v-for="element in list">
        <li>{{ element }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you tried it: https://vuejs.org/guide/transitions.html ?

Comment: @GONG, I read it, but couldn't figure out how to do it in my case. It seems from the official doc that transition can only be used with v-if, v-show etc. But I have none of them here.

Comment: `<ul v-for="element in list" transition="fade">` try in that way, it should work. According to docs "The transition attribute can be used together with: v-for (triggered for insertion and removal only)"

Comment: not working. Am i missing something? Is it possible to give a working example?

Comment: For sure, check my answer. Mark it as best if you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to official docs u need to wrap you loop with a `transition` element. And specify a `name` and a (optional) `tag` attributes.

Like so:

```html
<transition-group name="list" tag="p">
    <span v-for="item in list" class="list-item"></span>
</transition-group>
```

And add some css classes with name of transition:

```css
.list-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.list-enter-active, .list-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.list-enter, .list-leave-to /* .list-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(30px);
}
```

More info at the https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @FrankerZ Thanks for advice, fixed now

Comment: @GONG, thanks for the solution. But you are using 'dynamic binding' in your solution, as per documentation. It is not working without dynamic binding. Why?

Comment: oops, sorry. I tried it with the ":transition", rookie mistake. It's fine now. Don't know why i couldn't make it work earlier. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This doesn't work in 2018. Also, answer includes a link to a 3rd party plugin. This should be disclosed.